# Anyone know of a 2-1 mux chip?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I'm trying to find an IC implementing 2-1 multiplexers, but I could only seem to find chips like this: [SN54LVC157A - Quadruple 2-line to 1-line data selectors/multiplexers](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc157a.pdf).

Where there are 2 groups of multiple inputs and 1 of these groups is selected for the output (essentially a bunch of 2-1 muxes with shared select inputs). Instead, I want 2-1 muxes where there are separate select inputs. Anyone know of such a chip? Or is there a reason why these are not readily available?

Basically, we need to implement some combinational logic on a breadboard for a lab, and we found we could do it with significantly less gates if we use muxes.

Comment: Anything with multiple muxes on one chip? Maybe in a 14-pin package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several common logic ICs available in small/single versions today. The HC157 has a two-input version in the [74AUP1G157](http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/digital_multiplexers/series/74AUP1G157.html). This is a basic 2-to-1 multiplexer. The 2G157 Brian mentions in his answer has an additional enable input and complementary outputs.

As far as I know there are no multiple 2-to-1 digital logic multiplexers. But there's no reason not to use several 74AUP1G157s on your board. The 1G157 is available in a SOT1115 package, which is less than 1mm\$^2\$.

[image]

Three or even four of those are smaller than a typical 14-pin SMT package. May not be the easiest solution for DIY, though.

Answer (score 0):

TI [little logic mux/demux](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?familyId=1669&family=logic&uiTemplateId=SZVI_T&paramCriteria=no). You are looking for SN74xxx1G157., probably [SN74LVC2G157](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc2g157) which is a 2:1 mux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement something on a breadboard, you could use the [ADG1634 from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADG1633_1634.pdf), which has four independently-controlled analog SPDT switches (which can also switch digital signals) in a 20-pin TSSOP package.

[image]

You can use an adapter [like this one](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2200039) to convert to a DIP.

[image]

Note that they also exist in dual or single version. See [this overview](http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-switches/products/index.html#Analog_CMOS_Switches).

Comment: This is a good alternative to the digital mux, but you should be aware of switching glitches. Break-before-make time is 44ns typical, max not specified. If both inputs are low, and the output has a pull-up, you'll get a positive pulse when switching. The digital logic mux won't have this phenomenon. If you can avoid the glitch this is a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

The very common CD4053 is 3 independent MUXes on a PDIP chip. Plus being a jelly bean 4000 series, it will work on 3-15V so is pretty handy for breadboarding/experimentation. It is an analog switch, so can switch bidirectional digital signals as well.

http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/cd4053/cd4053.htm